# how to pass many variables in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I faced problems when I don't know how to pass many variables in `with_items:`

I have these vars:

```yaml
- vars:
    paths:
      - /tmp/tecom/python3/
      - /tmp/tecom/pip/
      - /tmp/tecom/psycopg2/
      - /tmp/tecom/docker/
      - /tmp/tecom/postgresql/
    files:
      - python3.tar
      - pip.tar
      - psycopg2.tar
      - docker.tar
      - postgresql.tar
```

And I have the task that should extract the archives:

```yaml
- name: unarchive "{{ item }}"
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: # should take the paths above. Every path should match it's own `.tar` file.
  with_items: "{{ files }}"
```

Every path should match its own `.tar` file.

Comment: See [mre] on how to simplify the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "unarchive {{ item }} to {{ _path }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      vars:
        _path: "{{ path }}/{{ item|splitext|first }}/"
        path: /tmp/tecom
        files:
          - python3.tar
          - pip.tar
          - psycopg2.tar
          - docker.tar
          - postgresql.tar
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: unarchive python3.tar to /tmp/tecom/python3/
  msg: unarchive pip.tar to /tmp/tecom/pip/
  msg: unarchive psycopg2.tar to /tmp/tecom/psycopg2/
  msg: unarchive docker.tar to /tmp/tecom/docker/
  msg: unarchive postgresql.tar to /tmp/tecom/postgresql/
```

---

Q: ***"How do I unarchive those files to the folders?"***

A: Use the expressions as appropriate, e.g.

```yaml
- name: "unarchive {{ item }}"
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ path }}/{{ item|splitext|first }}/"
  loop: "{{ files }}"
```

(not tested)

It's up to you where you put the variables *files* and *path*. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Comment: wow, this is realyl helpful! But how do i unarchive those files to the folders? 0_0

Comment: Using the unarchive module

Comment: i can't really get it how to improve the code you wrote to make it unarchive to the specific folders

Comment: I added an example.